# DKIM=Fail OpenSSL error: data too large for key size

Tags: openssl, dkim

Below is detailed info on the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
DKIM Signature

Message contains this DKIM Signature:
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=awp1.com;
     s=default; h=Content-Type:Mime-Version:Subject:From:To:Date:Sender:Reply-To:
    Message-ID:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description:
    Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:
    In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:
    List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
    bh=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=; b=hjFILYWdG5vAk56ssyvqVvZtJ7
    E3FqFYB9y1ssKz/UQfsZYByVm/GovpCDpymrEdqxiUzDhufi8U8hyCj0liKwBHzIWt7XNsrC+tv1M
    Jfu8EA4gt73ith7wL0p1LS+NXMmlaN3Efk7tKfNTnOjGJV1GHKidqCpYgHvZJ9WfOQPkQLvGJOw90
    A/wXHcBEBT8o749pSyqh739boijJm0yViKtgXdjdYpUO4IDFehFQ93fUNAW9hOQaW+76QlRUibwD6
    PkB86C1FzsRmKgVF+2oaRB1hK6tlZzEpw3PINqSFQks7ETk7qmx73qqkgvP5e5Q002NOSARYofjY2
    6ABU1BzA==;


Signature Information:
v= Version:         1
a= Algorithm:       rsa-sha256
c= Method:          relaxed/relaxed
d= Domain:          awp1.com
s= Selector:        default
q= Protocol:        dns/txt
bh=                 47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
h= Signed Headers:  Content-Type:Mime-Version:Subject:From:To:Date:Sender:Reply-To:
    Message-ID:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description:
    Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:
    In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:
    List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive
b= Data:            hjFILYWdG5vAk56ssyvqVvZtJ7
    E3FqFYB9y1ssKz/UQfsZYByVm/GovpCDpymrEdqxiUzDhufi8U8hyCj0liKwBHzIWt7XNsrC+tv1M
    Jfu8EA4gt73ith7wL0p1LS+NXMmlaN3Efk7tKfNTnOjGJV1GHKidqCpYgHvZJ9WfOQPkQLvGJOw90
    A/wXHcBEBT8o749pSyqh739boijJm0yViKtgXdjdYpUO4IDFehFQ93fUNAW9hOQaW+76QlRUibwD6
    PkB86C1FzsRmKgVF+2oaRB1hK6tlZzEpw3PINqSFQks7ETk7qmx73qqkgvP5e5Q002NOSARYofjY2
    6ABU1BzA==
Public Key DNS Lookup

Building DNS Query for default._domainkey.awp1.com
Retrieved this publickey from DNS: v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDMt3AOXxBH/50PNk4YJp2CtxiEFH8BU0+aIYNNXmZVtUOGJx6ZCW/UmwehExS3LTJrM4DtzGLr2gaOdASOIoD+GMiZVa69PhjWCaFm/6D1dzDOzCUP/W89HHPIFMas7v6LMSg3jIvBnLWVYJbmiH9yu1C5xTzKt7Bfk27QmUJZiQIDAQAB;
Validating Signature

result = fail
Details: OpenSSL error: data too large for key size
```

Answer (score 2):

The publickey in the DNS (default._domainkey.awp1.com) seems to be a 1024 bit long RSA key ([link to decoded key](http://www.lapo.it/asn1js/#30819F300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818D0030818902818100CCB7700E5F1047FF9D0F364E18269D82B71884147F01534F9A21834D5E6655B54386271E99096FD49B07A11314B72D326B3380EDCC62EBDA068E74048E2280FE18C89955AEBD3E18D609A166FFA0F57730CECC250FFD6F3D1C73C814C6ACEEFE8B3128378C8BC19CB5956096E6887F72BB50B9C53CCAB7B05F936ED0994259890203010001))

The length of the RSA signature in the DKIM signature (the b-tag, base64 encoded) is 2048 bit.

But for RSA, [the key size and the size of the signature should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6662179).

OpenSSL wherefore rightfully complains about the signature size (2048 bit) being to  large for used key (1024 bit).